# Reading big json dataset using pandas with chunks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to read a json of 6gb size (and I've another of 1.5gb), and i tried to read normally with pandas (just with pd.read_json), and clearly memory dies.
Then, I tried with chunksize param, like:

```
with open('data/products.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    df = []
    df_reader = pd.read_json(f, lines=True, chunksize=1000000)
    for chunk in df_reader:
        df.append(chunk)
data = pd.read_json(df)
```

But that doesn't work too, and my pc dies on the first running minute (8gb RAM actually).

Comment: You are reading data in chunks, but again you are appending the whole dataset into `df` and it's going out of memory.

Comment: So, how can i read the entire data without going out? Pandas with chunksize returns JsonReader object

Comment: Read in `chunks`, `process` that chunk and continue. I cannot give you more insights since I don't know what you want to do with that data.

Comment: I want to start analyzing the data (Ive worked on the past with datsets ~300mb, but never that size), in order to clean the data and start doing dashboards, using sklearn, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Dask and Pyspark has dataframe solutions that are nearly identical to `pandas`. Pyspark is a Spark api and distributes workloads across JVMs. Dask specifically targets the out-of-memory on a single workstation use case and implements the dataframe api.

As shown [here](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_json) `read_json`'s api mostly passes through from pandas.

As you port your example code from the question, I would note two things:

1. I suspect you won't need the file context manager, as simply passing the file path probably works.
2. If you have multiple records, Dask supports blobs like "path/to/files/*.json"